# Clear/Delete the values picked off a lightning-checkbox-group

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning, lwc

My goal is to clear all the checkbox checks when I move from one lightning-tab to another. I use the lightning-tab **onactive={handleTabClick}** function to clear all the field inputs when moving from one tab to another. The following code clears regular input boxes but not the **lightning-checkbox-group**:

```
    handleTabClick(){
            this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input[data-id="weekly"]').forEach(element 
            => {
                 element.value = null;
            });
           this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-checkbox-group[data-id="weekly"]').forEach(element => {
                element.value = null
           });
           this.valueWeekly = null
           this.skipEveryWeek = null
    }
```

Here's my HTML:

**LWC HTML:**

```
<div class="slds-var-m-around_medium slds-box">
        <h1 class="slds-var-m-around_medium">Recurrence pattern</h1>
        <div class="slds-border_top slds-border_bottom">
            <lightning-tabset>
                <lightning-tab label="Daily" onactive={handleTabClick} value="Daily">
                    For daily Service Appointments simpy select a Start Date and End Date from the datepickers
                    below.
                </lightning-tab>
                <lightning-tab label="Weekly" onactive={handleTabClick} value="Weekly">
                    <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-inline-block-links_space">
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group" options={optionsWeekly}
                                    value={valueWeekly} onchange={handleChangeWeekly} data-id="weekly">
                                </lightning-checkbox-group>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <p>
                                    <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                        value="          "></lightning-formatted-text>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                <lightning-input
                                    label="(Skips every # of weeks)" type="number" value={skipEveryWeek} 
                                    onkeyup={handleRecurEveryWeek} data-id="weekly">
                                </lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    <lightning-formatted-text 
                                        class="slds-var-m-around_medium" value="week(s)">
                                    </lightning-formatted-text>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </lightning-tab>
                <lightning-tab label="Monthly" onactive={handleTabClick} value="Monthly">
                    <lightning-accordion class="example-accordion" onsectiontoggle={handleToggleSection}
                        active-section-name="Day">
                        <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                        <lightning-accordion-section name="Day" label="Day" onclick={handleMonthlyDay}>
                            <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-inline-block-links_space">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <lightning-input class="daymonth" label="Day of Month" type="number"
                                            value={dayOccurrenceMonth} onkeyup={handleMontlyDayMonth}
                                            data-id="monthly">
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <p>
                                            <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                                value="of every"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <lightning-input class="recurmonth" label="(Skips every # of months)" type="number"
                                            value={skipEveryMonth1} onkeyup={handleRecurEvery1}
                                            data-id="monthly">
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <p>
                                            <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                                value="month(s)"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                        <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                        <lightning-accordion-section name="Week Day" label="Week Day">
                            <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-inline-block-links_space">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <lightning-combobox name="progress" value={valueEvery}
                                            placeholder="Select Progress" options={optionsEvery}
                                            onchange={handleChangeEvery} data-id="monthly">
                                        </lightning-combobox>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <lightning-combobox name="progress" value={valueWeekday}
                                            placeholder="Select Progress" options={optionsWeekday}
                                            onchange={handleChangeWeekday} data-id="monthly">
                                        </lightning-combobox>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <p>
                                            <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                                value="of every">
                                            </lightning-formatted-text>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <lightning-input type="number" value={skipEveryMonth2} onkeyup={handleRecurEvery2}
                                            data-id="monthly">
                                        </lightning-input>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="page-section page-right">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <p>
                                            <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                                value="month(s)">
                                            </lightning-formatted-text>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                        <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                    </lightning-accordion>
                </lightning-tab>
                <lightning-tab label="Yearly" onactive={handleTabClick} value="Yearly">
                    <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-inline-block-links_space">
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <lightning-input label="Day of Year" type="number" data-id="yearly"
                                    value={dayOccurrenceYear} onkeyup={handleYearlyDay}>
                                </lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                        value="of every">
                                    </lightning-formatted-text>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <lightning-input label="(Skips every # of years)" type="number"
                                    value={skipEveryYear} onkeyup={handleRecurEveryYear}
                                    data-id="yearly">
                                </lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="page-section page-right">
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <p>
                                    <lightning-formatted-text class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
                                        value="year(s)" >
                                    </lightning-formatted-text>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </lightning-tab>
            </lightning-tabset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have an Array or List variable "valueWeekly" that I've been able to nullify, but unsuccessfully nullify the visual representation in the UI.

Here are some Before and After screenshots
**Before:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYalD.png)

**After**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6ns4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was nullifying the **valueWeekly** array instead of just emptying it. Now I'm initializing the array empty in the **onactive={handleTabClick}** function/method like the following code:

```
handleTabClick(){
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input[data-id="weekly"]').forEach(element => {
        element.value = null;
    });
           
    this.valueWeekly = [] // previously: this.valueWeekly = null 
    this.skipEveryWeek = null
}
```